# квадратные скобки в javascript

Tags: javascript

Учу js, запутался в этом коде:

```
var eventMixin = {
on: function(eventName, handler) {
if (!this._eventHandlers) this._eventHandlers = {};
if (!this._eventHandlers[eventName]) {
this._eventHandlers[eventName] = [];
}
this._eventHandlers[eventName].push(handler);
}}
```

Что означает эта запись?

```
this._eventHandlers[eventName],
```

`[eventName]` это свойство eventHandlers или что?  Можете объяснить?

Comment: к свойству объекта можно получить двумя способами: через точечную нотацию `object.property` и и скобочную нотацию `object[property]` [источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: @Bald значит это свойство?

Comment: да, `eventName` это свойство объекта `eventHandlers`

Comment: @Bald, класс. Спасибо. Можно еще один вопрос по js?

Comment: через кнопку **Задать вопрос** ;)

Comment: @Bald мне просто нужно будет тогда 1.5 часа ждать чтобы задать его(. Я обновил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: что бы иметь возможность задавать вопросы чаще чем раз в 1,5 часа рекомендую ознакомится со справкой

Comment: @Bald, посмотрел. не нашел ничего про 1.5 часа

Comment: где то на сайте я читал что в некоторых случаях система ограничивает участника, для получения более конкретного ответа, задайте вопрос на мете, основное про задаваемые вопросы, в этом [разделе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Если появился новый вопрос - надо задавать новый вопрос, а не полностью переписывать уже имеющийся

Comment: @Grundy я так и делал, но мне писали другие опытные чуваки отсюда, что не нужно плодить вопросы, а менять уже существующий, а вы наоборот говорите, вот я и не знаю как быть то теперь:)

Comment: Уточнения вопроса нужно дописывать, а не плодить новые вопросы. Полностью новые вопросы нужно задавать отдельно новые, а не переписывать старые. Все чуваки вам говорили правильно

Comment: @AsasSas, тут два момента: 1. задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз не нужно. 2. Полностью менять текст вопроса тоже не нужно.

Comment: @Grundy окей, понятно. спасибо